# kubectl drain node --dry-run not showing errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have a deployment A where replica count is set to 1 and in Pod Disruption budget `minAvailable` is also set to 1. Upon describing PDB, it shows ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS as 0 but the problem is when I do `kubectl drain node-1 --dry-run` , the output still shows the above deployment pod evicted. Is it like dry run does not show errors ? I am using Kubernetes 1.19

Comment: are you using ```—dry-run=client``` or ```dry-run=server``` ?

Comment: @PavolKrajkovič  I used --dry-run=client

Comment: ```k drain --ignore-daemonsets --delete-emptydir-data --dry-run=server nodename``` try this

Comment: Yes, by running the server dry run you can get a better overview about the state of the pods. Client side dry run only prints the object that would be sent

Comment: @Adiii --delete-emptydir-data  is not supported by kubectl drain. Kube version 1.19.11

Comment: then `--delete-local-data` this should work for 1.19.1

Comment: @Adiii so I tried this command ```kubectl drain --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data --dry-run=server stack-slave1``` and see this error
```error when evicting pod "my-pod-fbbf75dbf-jc5vm": /, Kind= doesn't support dry-run```.    I was expecting some msg like ```error when evicting pod my-pod (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.```

Comment: which version of Kubernetes server?

Comment: @Adiii ```v1.19.11```

Comment: is this cloud provider? or self hosted? i did not find anything here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?q=Kind%3D+doesn%27t+support+dry-run

Comment: this one is self hosted